# Change background color of checked combobox in datagridview on button click using MVVM

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

Hi I am new in WPF I want change background color of selected row. please help me in this
Itemsource for datagrid id Data property which is INotify Used to crate combobox (This Work Fine) 
IsChecked is Property for Checkbox 
please note that combobox and check box are dynamically created

```
  <DataGrid Name="lbUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding  Data}" CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectionIndexChange, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rule Type" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.RuleType}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.RuleType, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                         />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox  Width="45" Height="20"  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=lbUsers,Path=DataContext.IsChecked}" ></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectionIndexChange, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rule Type" Width="100">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RuleType}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.RuleType, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  Width="45" Height="20"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```